# Shadows not Showing up? Also help with color variation in shaders

Tags: modifiers, shaders, lighting, shadows

**Here is a link to the blend file**

[Click here to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rbSa3n3EWEVYxSwO49EbrgmZkMmkHzMj/view?usp=sharing)
I created this set of gumdrops with an array modifier. The Rectangle underneath is shaded to like marble and has a couple of image textures and BSDF settings. It isn't really catching the shadows but the reflections and whatnot are visible. I'm assuming the problem is the shader on the plane but I don't know how to fix it.

I really doubt it's a settings thing or lighting issue. The only active light I got in the scene is an area light with a reasonable amount of watts.
As you can see, in the image the shadows are too "red" when
I try out on a blank plane with no shader adjustments(Exhibit A). Meanwhile, with my makeshift marble shader it looks goofy as well (Exhibit B). Any takes?

I included the blend file and some images.A
[image]

B[image]

Heres a pic of the marble shader from exhibit B.
[image]
PS. anyways that aside, I also want these gumdrops to be different colors but don't know how to do so because it's an array modifier, amimated, and I dont know where to put the color ramp in my nodes to make it happen.

If any of yall know I'd be very happy[image]

Comment: Your renders look a little blown-out, like your lighting is perhaps too strong. Is it possible that the lighting conditions are simply too extreme to get much in the way of noticeable shadows? Maybe try reducing the intensity of the lights and checking if that changes anything?

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought too. I messed with the lighing radius, watts,  position, angle, you name it. @AlexisKing  I adjusted it once more and the scene looks dimmer, but the problem remains

Comment: can you provide your blend file please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rbSa3n3EWEVYxSwO49EbrgmZkMmkHzMj/view?usp=sharing @Chris here ya go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Right here you are telling a *Transparent BSDF* to amplify the light passing through the gumdrops in a non-realistic way.  Stick to *Value* and *Saturation* in the 0 - 1 range to produce realistic results.

*Geometry* -> *Random Per Island* is the key to separating out an array.

[image]

You could replace the *Viewer* here with your *Color Ramp*.